# What is the easiest way to append a string

Tags: c#

Say　I have a function `List<string> list` with content `{"a","b","c","d"}`

is it possible to have a return statement like

`return list union {"d"}` //Which is essentially `{"a","b","c","d","d"}`

if yes what is the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
return list.Concat(new[] {"d"}).ToList();
```

This statement does not alter contents of `list`.
The `Concat` method, is an extension method provided by LINQ, so make sure you have the following `using` statement on top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Not sure if it's obvious to william007 or not so I'll mention it: Please note that this code does not alter the original list so after this call, the original list will still only contain "a","b" & "c"

Comment: Hi thanks, but there is one problem:if original list have {"a","b","c"}, if I append a {"c"}, it will becomes {"a","b","c"}, what I want is  {"a","b","c","c"} (multi-set), how should I achieve this? edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @william007 I'm sorry. It should be `Concat` instead of `Union`. I updated the answer.